# Adding .not() on event handling to dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery

With event handling on dynamically added content, I use:

```
$('#static-div').on('click', '.dynamic-content', function () {
    // do something
});
```

What should I do if I want to add a .not() to this code?
As in, I want to click anything with ".dynamic-content" but not apply the event handling to ".should-not-be-clicked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add :not() to the selector

```js
$('#static-div').on('click', '.dynamic-content:not(.no)', function () {
    console.log('clicked')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="static-div">
  <button type="button" class="dynamic-content">Y</button>
  <button type="button" class="dynamic-content no">N</button>
  <button type="button" class="dynamic-content">Y</button>
  <button type="button" class="dynamic-content no">N</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a not css selector which you can add to this.

Check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp)

```
$('#static-div').on('click', '.dynamic-content:not(.should-not-be-clicked) ', function () {
    // do something
});
```